# Compilation error for NDIS driver with Visual Studio 2012! :(

Tags: visual-studio, wdk, ndis

I am trying to compile the NDIS driver using Visual studio 2012 Express for Desktop.
I have installed WDK 8.1 already but still couldnot manage to get it...

I suspect that somewhere i have to include the path for the MSbuild tools but unfortunately i have no ideally how to do it.

This is the error message:

error MSB8020: The builds tools for WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1 to build using the WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1 build tools.    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets 44 5 ndisprot630

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 Express can't be integrated with WDK - you need at least Professional version.

Comment: I have professional version now. could you please guide me how to do it.

Comment: I'm wondering who has decided to downvote this answer after 2 years, especially given that it's 100% correct.